# [JS][AJAX] second ajax does not work. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have little problem :) The first ajax returns the correct value.
Then I extract the text from the first answer and I want to send this text to another ajax file. but the second one sends an empty value. Why?
So this is my code:

```
var fileName = "record.wav";
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('file', blob);
$.ajax({
  url: "sendFileAudio.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: formdata,
  // async: true,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#loaderStt").show();
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var messagesContainerOther = $(".messages");
    messagesContainerOther.append(
      data
    );
    var audioRsp = $(data).text();
    var pytanie = audioRsp.valueOf();
    // alert(typeof audioRsp);
    document.getElementById("wiadomosc").innerHTML = pytanie;
    // var pytanie = $("#wiadomosc").text();     
    $.ajax({
      url: "sendMessageSamara.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: pytanie,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loader").show();
      },
      success: function(data) {
        // console.log(data);                                         
        // alert("2"+ref);                                         
        console.log("poszło");
        console.log(pytanie);
        var messagesContainerOther = $(".messages");
        messagesContainerOther.append(
          data
        );
        messagesContainerOther.finish().animate({
            scrollTop: messagesContainerOther.prop("scrollHeight")
          },
          250
        );
      },
      complete: function(data) {
        $("#loader").hide();
      },
    });
  },
  complete: function(data) {
    $("#loaderStt").hide();
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't sending a key/value pair in the second request, only a value

Change

```
data: pytanie
```

to

```
data: {somePropertyName: pytanie}
```

And receive that in php with:

```
$_POST['somePropertyName'];
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is request being made? inspect it in browser dev tools network and see what is sent is what you expect, status etc

Comment: i add before: contentType: 'text/plain', haha :)